# Why I am getting this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver Whereas i am giving class path?

Tags: java, jdbc, terminal, runtime-error

First of all i am new to java. I know there are many same questions but all of them are related with IDE's and i am compiling and running directly on terminal, it is compiling perfectly but throwing class not found error and sql error. i am compiling with cp like this

```
javac -cp /Users/Schmidthakid/Documents/UOW/Java/Assignments/Assignment2/Assignment2Files/derby.jar:/Users/Schmidthakid/Documents/UOW/Java/Assignments/Assignment2/Assignment2Files/au/edu/uow/QuestionDB/*:/Users/Schmidthakid/Documents/UOW/Java/Assignments/Assignment2/Assignment2Files/au/edu/uow/QuestionLibrary/*:/Users/Schmidthakid/Documents/UOW/Java/Assignments/Assignment2/Assignment2Files/au/edu/uow/UserInterface/*: JavaQuizDB.java
```

Errors:

[image: These are the errors]

QuestionDB, QuestionLibrary and Userinterface are actually packages so i have to give their paths otherwise it is not loading any of them. If anyone have knowledge related to this please share & guide me. Ill be very thankful to you.

Comment: The classpath you show is being given to the compiler (`javac`). That exception instead occurs when you _run_ the compiled code. You must provide the classpath when you run your code.

Comment: Include in your question your full command for running the class too. The java .class files don't retain any knowledge of the libs you used in the compilation phase when you run them, so you have to include all the relevant jars in the running of the classes too.

Comment: @MarkFisher I think the command for running the class is the top line in the screenshot. MQ, that's where you should provide the `-cp ...` just like you did with `javac`.

Comment: it worked @SantiBailors many thanks man :)